# Callback after every `each` iteration when `next` is called

Tags: ruby

I want to run some code after every iteration of `each`. Is there a way to do this without repeating the code? I tried this:

```
(1..10).each do |n|
  continue = Proc.new {
    puts "ended #{n}"
    next
  }
  continue.call if n == 2
  puts n
  continue.call
end
```

but it didn't work.

In my actual code, I have lots of `next` calls. That's why it's unpractical to call a method every time I call `next`.

Comment: In what way did it not work?  What do you want it to do, and what did it actually do?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As I understand the question, you don't want anything executed after `continue.call` if `n==2`. If that's correct, you could use the control expression [next](http://docs.ruby-lang.org/en/2.2.0/syntax/control_expressions_rdoc.html#label-next+Statement) with an argument.

```
def m(n)
  puts "Only #{n} more days!"
end

(1..6).each do |n|
  next m(n) if n==3
  puts n
  m(n)
end
1
Only 1 more days!
2
Only 2 more days!
Only 3 more days!
4
Only 4 more days!
5
Only 5 more days!
6
Only 6 more days!
```

Answer (score 1):

#### Approach 1

Define the contents of the loop in a method that you call from the loop. You can put an `ensure` block in the method. That way, your method can use `return` anywhere you want to move onto the next iteration, but you still guarantee you execute the `ensure` code:

```
def doit(x)
  return if x == 2
  puts "I like the number #{x}"
ensure
  puts "LOOP"
end

[1,2,3,4].each{|x| doit(x)}
```

results in

```
I like the number 1
LOOP
LOOP
I like the number 3
LOOP
I like the number 4
LOOP
```

---

#### Approach 2

Similar to approach 1, but allows you reuse the "callback" code for different concerns. It also keeps you using `next` instead of `return`. This is to define a method that `yield`s and then does other stuff:

```
def ensure_LOOP(x)
  yield
  puts "LOOP"
end

[1,2,3,4].each do |x|
  ensure_LOOP(x) do
    next if x == 2
    puts "I really like the number #{x}"
  end
end
```

Results in

```
I really like the number 1
LOOP
LOOP
I really like the number 3
LOOP
I really like the number 4
LOOP
```

And

```
[1,2,3,4].each do |x|
  ensure_LOOP(x) do
    next unless x == 2
    puts "I don't like the number #{x}"
  end
end
```

results in

```
LOOP
I don't like the number 2
LOOP
LOOP
LOOP
```

Answer (score 0):

Just call it within the each loop?

```
(1..10).each do |n|
  puts n
  puts "ended #{n}"
end
```

Answer (score 0):

The code you provided actually *does* run, and outputs the following:

```
1
ended 1
ended 2
2
ended 2
3
ended 3
4
ended 4
5
ended 5
6
ended 6
7
ended 7
8
ended 8
9
ended 9
10
ended 10
```

As you can see, the `Proc` gets called twice for the number 2, as your `if` condition passes in that case and calls the `Proc`.

Stepping back, defining a method *outside* the context of the iteration is probably a better choice. It will make the code easier to read and avoid redefining the `Proc` each time the `each` block executes.

That said, technically what you have here seems to run okay.

Comment: I want the `Proc` to be called only once, because inside the Proc I call `next`, so it should never reach the second one.

Comment: Ah I see. Well since you're already conditioning inside the `each` block, why not just put the method calls inside the conditions as needed? I.e. do something if n == 2, else do something else.

Comment: I have a lot of `next` calls in my actual code, most of them inline, I wanted to simply replace them for a method, and call it at the end. But I think I'll go with that approach, thanks.